# How can I use a new version of an object in a loop, without it getting overriden?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that loops over an array of words, and checks if a string passed to the function contains any of the letters in the word. The word with the most matching letters is returned.

My issue is that the `const` I am copying to the loop scope is getting overriden. Specifically `let loopIndex = alphabetIndex;` How can I make a variable that I can manipulate in the loop, without it overriding the `const`?

```
import _forEach from 'lodash/foreach';
const dictionary = require('./dictionary.json');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Game = function () {
};

/**
 * @desc Return an object of the repeating string characters.
 * @param string
 * @returns {{}}
 */
Game.prototype.setAlphabet = function (string) {
  let alphabet = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    if (string[i] in alphabet) {
      alphabet[string[i]] += 1;
    } else {
      alphabet[string[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return alphabet;
};

/**
 * @desc Return the largest word using the string passed to the function.
 * @param string
 */
Game.prototype.getWinningWord = function (string) {
  let max      = 0;
  let maxIndex = 0;

  // Get the amount of letters used in the string as an object.
  const alphabetIndex = this.setAlphabet(string);

  // Loop through every word in the dictionary
  _forEach(dictionary, function (word, position) {
    let sum       = 0;
    let loopIndex = alphabetIndex;
    // For each of the letters, check the index; and if the letter exists in the word, add to the sum.
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i += 1) {
      if (loopIndex[word[i]] > 0) {
        sum += 1;
        loopIndex[word[i]] -= 1;
      }
    }
    // If the current word has more matching letters than the previous max, set this word to max.
    if (sum > max) {
      max      = sum;
      maxIndex = position;
    }
    if (position > 10) return false;
  });
  return dictionary[maxIndex];
};

/**
 * Init game.
 * @type {Game}
 */
var newGame = new Game();
console.log(newGame.getWinningWord('eeosnndsm'));
```

Comment: You'll have to make a copy of the `alphabetIndex` object on each iteration. The `const` declaration makes it impossible to change the value of the *variable* `alphabetIndex`, but not the contents of the object it refers to.

Comment: Unless Im missing something, you'd Just do something like myWorkingVersion = yourOldObject.   then do whatever you need to do with myWorkingVersion (the copy of the original object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction here is that while a `const` variable can never be *assigned* to again, if the value of that variable is a *reference* then that reference can change. To avoid this, you need to make a new copy in each iteration of your loop, a simple way to do this is to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let loopIndex = Object.assign({}, alphabetIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was driving me nuts!